# How to not animate specific constraint changes with layoutIfNeeded() in Swift?

Tags: swift, animation, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a UIView which contains subviews. The subviews are animated with constraints changes and layoutIfNeeded() function :

```
for i in 1...cardViews.count - 1 {
    let currentCard = cardViews[i]
    let previousCard = cardViews[i-1]

    // Set new offset
    currentCard.topConstraint?.constant = previousCard.contentView.frame.height + configuration.expandedOffset
}

// To animate constraints's changes
UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(duration), delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: nil)
```

But when I do this, it also animate the contraints changes of the parent. Something like this :

```
self.Height == containerView.Height
```

How can I call layoutIfNeeded() to animate my subviews but not the parent ?

EDIT : The side effect :
http://gph.is/2noI3w9

Comment: Try manually calling `parent.layoutIfNeeded` immediately before you layout `self` in the animation block. This will force the parent to layout without animations before `self` lays out with animations

Comment: When I do `parent.layoutIfNeeded()` it animates all its subviews

Comment: How about if you call it before you update the constraints?

Comment: Doesn't work... :(
I think it's because the constraint that I don't want to animate is dynamic and depending of the subviews constraints

Comment: If the constraint of the parent is dependant on the constraints of the children, why do you not want them to animate together? It seems to me like the effect would be jarring if one animates but the other doesn't.

Comment: I added a gif to explain my problem

Answer (score 1):

You can call this inside of your UIView.animate

```
for i in 1...cardViews.count - 1 {
    let currentCard = cardViews[i]
    currentCard.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Instead of

```
self.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Did you add the layoutIfNeeded() inside the UIView.animate ? @Will

Comment: @Will if this is not the answer you are looking for please explain what you mean with "This brokes the animation"

Comment: When I say "Broke" that means that it's not animated. I added a gif to my question to be more explicit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138028/discussion-between-casper-zandbergen-and-will).